# How to set column width in kable()?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I have a data table I want to display for HTML report.
Her is a dummy table

```
BelQ= structure(list(Source = "Kalender 2019", `Sourse of Questions` = "The survey instruments were part of a larger survey that included other motivational constructs. The development and validation of these surveys is reported in prior work [18–22,59]. ",     Results = "PCA analysis reveals that for both genders, sense of belonging and identity were not separate from the Expectancy Value Theory constructs. Instead, sense of belonging was closely tied to self-efficacy, which was therefore labeled as “self-efficacy or belonging” component or factor. ", Questions = "Sense of Belonging or Self-efficacy (not separated in a paper):<br>1. Sometimes I worry that I do not belong in this physics class<br>2. I feel like I can be myself in this class<br>3. I am able to help my classmates with physics in the laboratory or in recitation<br>4. I understand concepts I have studied in physics<br>5. If I wanted to, I could be good at physics research<br>6. ",     Reference = "Kalender, Z. Y., Marshman, E., Schunn, C. D., Nokes-Malach, T. J., & Singh, C. (2019). Gendered patterns in the construction of physics identity from motivational factors. Physical Review Physics Education Research, 15(2), [020119](https://journals.aps.org/prper/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevPhysEducRes.15.020119)"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

when I try to produce a table I am not able to change teh widths of teh columns and I get teh error Error in UseMethod("nodeset_apply") : no applicable method for 'nodeset_apply' applied to an object of class "NULL"

```
BelQ  %>%
  kable(format = "html",escape = FALSE) %>%   kable_styling() %>% 
  scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "500px") %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "18em")
```

My code chunk has `{r results="asis" }`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but try putting your `column_spec` before `scroll_box` in your pipe... and also you might want a minimum width specified: `column_spec(1, width = "18em; min-width:18em;")` ... and did you want `kable_styling()` twice?

Comment: Hi Ben, yes you were right! Why I can add scroll_box before column_spec? and why width not working ut width_min is?

Comment: Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/164) which gave me some ideas...perhaps others may have more input on this...

Comment: thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but `scroll_box` should go to the end and `width_min` to be used

```
BelQ  %>%
  kable(format = "html",escape = FALSE) %>%   
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>% 
  column_spec(1, width_min = "18em")%>%
  scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "500px")
```